# Smsgateway.me with visual foxpro, is PHP

Tags: php, sms, visual-foxpro

I'm trying to use the SMS gateway from smsgateway.me in a software that works in VFP.

Anyone can help me to implement the PHP code in VFP?

The code is in: https://smsgateway.me/sms-api-documentation/messag...

PHP Code:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use SMSGatewayMe\Client\ApiClient;
use SMSGatewayMe\Client\Configuration;
use SMSGatewayMe\Client\Api\MessageApi;
use SMSGatewayMe\Client\Model\SendMessageRequest;

// Configure client
$config = Configuration::getDefaultConfiguration();
$config->setApiKey('Authorization', 'your-token-here');
$apiClient = new ApiClient($config);
$messageClient = new MessageApi($apiClient);

// Sending a SMS Message
$sendMessageRequest1 = new SendMessageRequest([
'phoneNumber' => '07791064781',
'message' => 'test1',
'deviceId' => 1
]);
$sendMessageRequest2 = new SendMessageRequest([
'phoneNumber' => '07791064781',
'message' => 'test2',
'deviceId' => 2
]);
$sendMessages = $messageClient->sendMessages([
$sendMessageRequest1,
$sendMessageRequest2
]);
print_r($sendMessages);
```

Answer (score 1):

Look into using Chilkat to send SMS through VFP, instead of the native foxpro ways.
Chilkat made it very easy for me, sending and receiving text messages (with or without media files) from within foxpro code. Where you can automate things, putting them into `DO`/`ENDDO` loops etc. I use Twilio services but the same concept should work with smsgateway.

Good luck,
Sime

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for help.
I find another way, and use a Android APK to create a SMS gateway direct in the phone.
I gona post another asking for help